# Combine a pipe of two core.async channels into one

Tags: clojure, core.async

I have a pipe of two channels *A* and *B*, processing looks like than `A --> operation --> B`. The inputs are put into *A* and the results are read from *B*.

I'd like to have a channel *C* which on `put!` would put the value to *A* and on new value emitted from *B* would emit that value too. So it would wrap the *A* and *B* channels into one channels. The read port of *A* would be *C*'s read port, and the write port of *B* would be the write port for *C*.

How to do that simply? Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: I think you can't do it and it is semantically wrong. I think you should use `defrecord` instead of channel C here. It could implement put/read operations like you wish.

Comment: @fl00r, I found such a solution https://github.com/jarohen/chord/blob/6e9c461cb7edbddf903bedc66540529000a0614a/src/chord/channels.cljc#L37, seems to be just the thing, I guess you've meant something similar... implementing `ReadPort`, `WritePort` and `Channel` to a `defrecord` instead of using `reify`...

Comment: Yes, I think it would be more idiomatic

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your requirements, and I'm not sure I do, there are two possible solutions I can think of.

The first is the pipline command, which will allow you to connect in and out channels and setup processing in the middle, which can be further paralleled to improve performance.

However, from your description, I think you might find alts! a better solution. this will allow you to define multiple input channels where you can take data from one or the other, process the data and then put it into an output channel.

Answer (score -1):

Gidday mate,

Am I correct in understanding you want channel C to be both an input and output? I'm not sure this is possible with "vanilla" channel operations; as soon as B puts onto C, then A would pick it up again. You really need separate input and output channels.

What are you trying to solve that needs this structure? Perhaps it could be solved another way?